# Mongodb, '$' cannot work with AND terms?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use '$' to update a certain item in a list. The item is determined by both firstName AND lastName, and in this scenario, firstName + lastName combination is unique.

So here is my document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("592403125ec4f65fb02e36a0"),
"friends" : [ 
    {
        "age" : 30.0,
        "fname" : "qiang",
        "lname" : "he"
    }, 
    {
        "age" : 31.0,
        "fname" : "deng",
        "lname" : "pan"
    }, 
    {
        "age" : 22.0,
        "fname" : "xiong",
        "lname" : "lan"
    },
    {
        "age" : 23.0,
        "fname" : "qiang",
        "lname" : "lan"
    }
]
}
```

So I'm trying to change the age of Qiang Lan, which is item 3 in the list. But he has the same firstName with item 0 and same lastName with item 2. The code I use is:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({'friends.fname': 'qiang', 'friends.lname': 'lan'}, {$set:{'friends.$.age': 50}})
```

This code did not change the age of Qiang Lan, but it changed item 0 Qiang He's age to 50, which is the earliest match of one of my terms. So the terms is actually treated as OR, not AND.

I know this can be solved by adding a fullName field which equals to firstName + lastName, and match the fullName on update. I'm just trying to figure out, is '$' designed to act like this on purpose, or am I using it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You in fact want [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here, as it's intended usage is for "multiple conditions on the same array item":

```js
db.getCollection('test').update(
    { "friends": { "$elemMatch": { "fname": 'qiang', "lname": 'lan'} },
    { "$set":{ "friends.$.age": 50 } }
)
```

Without the `$elemMatch` the query conditions are considering the "whole" array, and will match either "fname" or "lname" in **any** array element. This is why `update()` complains.

Answer (score 0):

try using and condition.

> $and performs a logical AND operation on an array of two or more
>   expressions (e.g. , , etc.) and selects the
>   documents that satisfy all the expressions in the array.

```
db.getCollection('test').update({$and:[{'friends.fname': 'qiang'}, {'friends.lname': 'lan'}], {$set:{'friends.$.age': 50}})
```

Comment: [All mongodb query arguments are already an "AND" condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-and-conditions). So `$and` offers nothing here, and this is not it's intended usage. The query here is in essence exactly the same as in the OP's question, which is producing the error.